# The future of the applications/software tag(s)

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-block-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Applications, application and software tags must die!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3448/applications-application-and-software-tags-must-die)

To my mind [applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/applications), [application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application) and [software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software) is useless - there is no clear meaning to them. Some questions should be tagged [software-recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) instead, but on other questions there is no need for it at all.

Should every question about any application be tagged with one of these? I think not.

What should we do with them?

Comment: There is also an `application` tag should this be included?

Comment: @Cas yep I think so (I've updated the question accordingly)

Answer (score 12):

### YES, remove them.

I cannot see any useful use of the tag, so I propose that:

1. Community members go through the tag page, and on relevant questions replace the *applications* tag by *software-recommendations*.
2. After this is completed, all other uses of the *applications* tag are removed (by a moderator in some way)
3. The *applications* tag is blacklisted so it cannot be used

Comment: I'm down with that.

Comment: @Marco I've completed stage #1... if you can set the wheels in motion for #2/3 that would be much appreciated

Comment: Seems to be a resurgence of `applications` tags.  I killed a lot, but there are still close to 50.  Some of them I've not touched because a better tag wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: @jgbelacqua sometimes there isn't a direct replacement needed, because the other tags on the question sum it up fine. still it sometimes seems silly just removing 50 tags when a (super) moderator could do it

Comment: I agree -- need to get a blacklist in place.   The questions I was having trouble with were ones where there were no appropriate tags -- I'm assuming that someone who's been here a little longer has a better sense of available and appropriate tags.

Answer (score -2):

### No

These tags are awesome, administrative burden is my kind of thing.