# Software tag too meta, delete?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The future of the applications tag(s)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/806/the-future-of-the-applications-tags)

I ran into [software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software) today and it's pretty meta/worthless. I've gone through and retagged the ones that should be software recommendations in the past, but I checked up on it today and it's kind of a mess.

Somehow the description is now:

> Questions related to software, including Linux alternatives to Windows programs.

Which conflicts with what software-recommendations is supposed to be.