# Applications, application and software tags must die!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

> **Originally discussed here:**
>   [The future of the applications/software tag(s)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/806/the-future-of-the-applications-software-tags)
>   <sub>Needs to be discussed again as an effort to ban the tags permanently</sub>

[applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/applications), [application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application) and [software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software) are useless - they have no usefulness to sort out posts or follow them, but users keep using them because they are suggested by the system or because they do not know what to use as tags for their post.

Should we ask the community to blacklist them so it is not a suggestion or a user cannot tag posts with them anymore?

Do you see any meaning or think they are useful?

Comment: I feel slightly bitter about the [stealing of my question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/806/the-future-of-the-applications-software-tags) (and answer!), but please please please let's get rid of these horrific tags!

Comment: @fluteflute it was a request from the SE community that the issue would be again discussed since your post was too old. If I copied its because it was perfect and would not change anything on it. While your post and answers were useful this is necessary to actually make the request to black list the tags. We cannot reset posts to 0 and start discussing them again so I am left with 2 options, copy and close or copy and delete. Don't get bitter for that, its just another day in moderation land :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tags have been removed from all questions and blacklisted.

Comment: Good job, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### YES, remove them.

I cannot see any useful use of the tag, so I propose that:

1. Community members go through the tag page, and on relevant questions replace the *applications* tag by *software-recommendations*.
2. After this is completed, all other uses of the *applications* tag are removed from posts where it is not relevant to use them.
3. The *applications* tag is blacklisted so it cannot be used.

Answer (score -4):

### No, do not remove them.

I think the tag is useful and should stay.

(If you have any points to add to this defending why the tags should stay edit the post)